# C# - I want to print a word document without using word.interop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I do not want to have to install word on the server and so I do not want to use word.interop.

What I do want to do is print off a word document in my web application.
My class looks like this;

```
namespace SCD4.Models
{
    using Novacode;

    public class DocumentDocX
    {
        public DocumentDocX(string inputFile)
        {
            this.InputFile = inputFile;
        }

        public string  InputFile { get; set; }

        public void OutputLetter(string outputFile, string placeholder, string newText)
        {
            using (var document = DocX.Load(this.InputFile))
            {
                document.ReplaceText(placeholder, newText);
                document.SaveAs(outputFile);
                PrintDocument(outputFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DocX is an assembly I got from CodePlex and is easy to use, but does not print word documents.
I haven't written my PrintDocument method yet. How should I write it?

Comment: You want to manage a propriety format without the propriety application written to manage it? Doable, no doubt, potentially illegal for those implementing such things, and already done with endorsements from the proprietor for reusability. That only leaves the question: Why?

Comment: You could do it with [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Print+a+Document+with+Settings+and+Print+Preview+Dialog). However, you haven't explained what you're objection to using Word.Interop is? I can think of 2 reasons why you would not want to use it (cost, and because MS recommend not to use it unattended) - but I'm interested in yours as if it's cost then Aspose is not a suitable solution (it's quite expensive)

Comment: Although 3rd party libraries for manipulating Office documents exist, none of the ones I've used in the past had rendering support (i.e. you can't display or print documents with them).  You might be able to use OpenOffice automation to do what you want.  That would require a full OpenOffice installation.

Comment: @GrantThomas I can't see why it would be illegal to manage a proprietary format without the specific vendor's tool. Any risk (e.g. of falling foul of patents or copyright) would rest with the vendor of the tool, not the customer.

Comment: @RB. I can't say I would even try based on guesses.

Comment: Well, EPPlus is a wrapper for OpenOffice XML format (for Excel) and it survives quite happily in the wild (and is indeed an excellent addition to anyones library).  No reason to think something similar couldn't be developed for docx without fear of the wrath of Microsoft raining down.

Comment: I have been unable to use word.interop on the deployment server. I get an error and my efforts to find a solution on SO have been fruitless. Aspose looks good but we do not have it and it is a costly solution simply to print a document.